# How to get away from "rc buffer underflow" and "HTTP error 503 Server too busy" errors?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, opensuse, ffserver

I try to create video stream with ffmpeg and ffserver. I would like to use flv or mpeg1video encoders because looking at local ffmpeg alone those encoders provide pretty decent speed.

But when I try any of them with ffserver I get either "rc buffer underflow" error (when bitrate is smaller) or "HTTP error 503 Server too busy" (when I increase the bitrate to avoid the first error).

Is there some magic option which allow me to pass data to ffserver and avoid those errors?

My current config:

```
<Stream live.ts>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format mpegts

NoAudio

VideoCodec flv
VideoSize 600x600
VideoFrameRate 30
VideoBufferSize 5

AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
AVOptionVideo qmin 2
AVOptionVideo qmax 56
PreRoll 5
StartSendOnKey
VideoBitRate 1000
</Stream>
```

Comment: Just as a small FYI, `ffserver` was slated for discontinuation in 2016 and was [officially dropped as of January 2018](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFServer returns `503 Server too busy` when the bandwidth is exceeded. You can check the bandwidth usage on http://localhost:8090/stat.html (assuming the server is on localhost).

If you want to increase the bandwidth, just change the `MaxBandwidth` setting at the top of the config file, before the streams and feeds.

For example

```
MaxBandwidth 10000
```

sets a 10 Mb/s bandwidth, which should be more than enough for your stream.